# How do I create a covariance matrix in R from MATLAB code?

Tags: r, matlab

I need some help with porting MATLAB code to R.

Below is MATLAB code for creating the covariance matrix, where `Z` is a matrix of 17 columns and 27 rows.  `ehat` is a vector of 27 rows and 1 column.

```
omegahat=zeros(cols(Z),cols(Z));

for i=1:N    
    omegahat=omegahat+ehat(i)^2*Z(i,:)'*Z(i,:);   
end
```

How do I replicate a `for` loop in R that works similarly to this MATLAB code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.  This essentially mirrors what the MATLAB code is doing, but I do question its efficiency.  Also `cols` is not a function that is defined in MATLAB except for SQL tables.  I'm assuming you want to determine the total number of columns?  Use `size(Z,2)` for that instead.

In any case, for R, `t` denotes transpose, and to perform matrix multiplication, you must encapsulate the `*` operator in `%` signs.  As such:

```
omegahat <- matrix(0,ncol(Z),ncol(Z));
for (i in 1:N) { # N is 27 I suppose?
   omegahat <- omegahat + (ehat[i]^2 * Z[i,] %*% t(Z[i,]))
}
```

Here's a small test on a smaller matrix.  Supposing `Z` is:

```
Z =

 1     2     3     4
 5     6     7     8
 9    10    11    12
13    14    15    16
```

Also, let `ehat` be:

```
ehat = 

1   2   3   4
```

I'm also going to assume `N = 4`.

---

In MATLAB, this is the code to generate our output:

```
Z = vec2mat(1:16, 4);
ehat = 1:4;
N = 4;

omegahat = zeros(size(Z,2), size(Z,2)); %# Note the change
for i = 1 : N    
    omegahat = omegahat + ehat(i)^2*Z(i,:)'*Z(i,:);   
end
```

We thus get:

```
omegahat =

    3534        3844        4154        4464
    3844        4184        4524        4864
    4154        4524        4894        5264
    4464        4864        5264        5664
```

---

In R, this is the code to generate our output:

```
Z <- t(matrix(1:16,4,4))
ehat <- c(1,2,3,4)
N <- 4

omegahat <- matrix(0,ncol(Z),ncol(Z))
for (i in 1:N) {
   omegahat <- omegahat + (ehat[i]^2 * Z[i,] %*% t(Z[i,]))
}
```

We thus get:

```
> omegahat

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] 3534 3844 4154 4464
[2,] 3844 4184 4524 4864
[3,] 4154 4524 4894 5264
[4,] 4464 4864 5264 5664
```

Comment: @SaikatSarkar - You are very welcome. If this answer has helped you, please consider accepting it. This can be done by clicking on the checkmark icon just beneath the up and down arrows at the top of my post.  Good luck!